# Vertically center a div inside another div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to `vertical-align: middle` a div inside another div, but for some reason it's not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#wrapper {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}
#block {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'wrapper'> 
<div id = 'block'> I'm Block </div>
<div>
```

**PS:**  This is just an example, so no, I don't actually know the actual width and height of the divs, as they are dynamic, according to their contents, so please no margin-top: 125px, or padding-top: 125px answers, or answers like that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property applies only to *inline-level* and *table-cell* elements ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height)). In your code you're working with *block-level* elements.

Try this flexbox alternative:

```css
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;               /* establish flex container */
    align-items: center;         /* vertically center flex items */
}

#block {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='block'> I'm Block </div>
<div>
```

Learn more about flex alignment here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

***Browser support:*** *Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I normally do this.

```css
#wrapper {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
}
#block {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Easy way to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here a live view: https://jsfiddle.net/w9bpy1t4/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#block {
  border:         1px solid blue;
  margin:         25% 0;
  width:          500px;
  height:         250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But that's not what you looking for!

or like this:

```
#wrapper {
  border:         1px solid red;
  width:          500px;
  height:         500px;
  display:        table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#block {
  border:  1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width:   500px;
  height:  250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if u know the height of the inner div then u can use position relative on wrapper and position absolute in inner div with some margin. So css can be this

```
#wrapper {
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 }
#block {
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width: 500px;
 height: 250px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 50%;
 top: -125px;
 }
```