# how to make vertical align

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want this to be vertical middle align of div.i used vertical align but wont help .[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAb1f.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAb1f.jpg)

```
 <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-5">

                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-2">
                 <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-5">

                 </div>



             </div>
```

css:

```
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388462/vertically-center-a-div-inside-another-div

Comment: should be responsive as well

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Examples can be found in [this SO Documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/5070/vertical-centering).